# ¿Cómo llamar una API dentro de otra API en ASP.NET 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

estoy trabajando en una solución de Visual Studio que fue construida en ASP.NET 2.1 como un proyecto de consola. sin embargo funciona como web APIs. Necesito llamar a una API externa construida también en ASP.NET (desconozco versión) para recibir información en formato JSON. El detalle es que debemos crear una API para obtener los valores de esa API y luego organizarlos entre las distintas tablas que tenemos. Básicamente, necesitamos una API que llame a la otra y así guardar los datos donde debe.

¿Hay alguna forma de implementar esto? y ¿Cómo se debería hacer? Soy nueva en esto de hacer APIs con C#, ya he intentado con otros códigos en internet pero nada parece funcionar

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si hay forma de hacerlo usando HttpClient, es tan sencillo como hacer una llamada a la Api de esta manera:

```
   var response = await client.GetAsync($"http://api/recurso");
  
   var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   var result = JArray.Parse(content);
```

si quieres mas información puedes encontrarla en la documentación oficial:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-2.1

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @TheOligarch, el GET ya me da respuesta, probaré hacerlo con el POST